# Is there any way to wrap a cardano native asset to eth?

Tags: native-assets, ada

I am looking for wrapping some native cardano tokens to the etherium network is there any way to achieve the same? Any help or urls will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with Milkomeda C1 sidechain and Nomad bridge. See the Ethereum to Cardano walkthrough here: https://medium.com/@wingriderscom/how-to-transfer-erc20-assets-to-cardano-ba9c7b9b5a5

Comment: there is only limitted number of tokens are available if i want to wrap a token which is not in at thease list what i have to do for example a nft.

Comment: I am accepting the answer how ever there is no way to wrap many tokens out there nfts also a problem now.